# which is better for services xml format or json

Tags: iphone, xml, json

We are now using xml formats for the service calls. The responses are larger. But heard json is faster for the service calls.

Can any one tell me which is better to use...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xml+json and please accept more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/json-vs-xml-the-debate) should solve your doubts

Cheers